# Django:MEDIA_ROOT error : _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple

Tags: python, django, runtime-error, typeerror

I am new to Django Framework. I am trying to upload an image to the customer table and this error occurs:

```
_getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike
```

I am using this code to upload:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = [BASE_DIR, 'static/images']
```

I changed the code to

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

but it says `NameError: name 'os' not defined`. What's the reason for the errors and how solve them?

***settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR, 'static']
MEDIA_ROOT = [BASE_DIR, 'static/images']
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem, this probably works
change it to this :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and for the error `os` not defined you just have to import it

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + 'static/images'
```

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/